# getElementById Value not coming properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field with Id table

```
<input type="text" class="form-control box_ip" placeholder="Table" id="Table" value="<table></table>"></input>
```

From the input field based on Id i am checking

```
this.table.forEach((id) => {
       console.log(id);  //Table
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log(element); //<input type="text" class="form-control box_ip" placeholder="Table" id="Table" value="<table></table>"></input>
        console.log(element.value); //showing empty expected output <table></table>
        if (element != undefined) {
            if (element.value != undefined && element.value != '') {
            this.replaceText(id, element.value);



            }
        }
    })
```

In the console of element i am getting   properly

```
          <input type="text" class="form-control box_ip" placeholder="Table" 
          id="Table" value="<table></table>">
.
```

but if i console

```
console.log(element.value);
```

I am getting empty value.
expected :

```
<table></table>
```

Comment: what is the output of document.getElementById("Table").value?

Comment: your code (up to `replaceText`) works fine https://jsfiddle.net/oxa60s6L/ ... not sure what `replaceText` is, but then, not sure what `this` is in the code you supplied

Comment: console.log(document.getElementById("Table").value); getting empty

Comment: @JaromandaX
outside of if  i console elements its coming but element.value showing empty value why?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle with your issue? it works fine for me - https://jsfiddle.net/oxa60s6L/1/

Comment: Use snippet here and show us what exactly isn't working. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: updated the question can you please check

Comment: you say `//showing empty expected output <table></table>` but there are at least two fiddles with your code that don't "show empty" ... you're doing something wrong elsewhere in your code, like ... clearing the value of your input